# How does a PC detect a DisplayPort monitor?

Tags: display

I need a PC to boot without a screen connected, however the motherboard does not allow me to. I tried to contact the tech support of the company but that was of little help.

I was wondering if there is a way to trick the motherboard into thinking a monitor is connected. I could find many easy hacks for a VGA connector, but none for DisplayPort, which my PC uses. I unfortunately do not have enough space to use some kind of DisplayPort to VGA adapter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170546/how-does-a-pc-detect-a-vga-monitor

Comment: Your problem is with display port and the operating system, not the electronics of display port.  The BIOS of your computer can't use display port, so nothing you do electronically matters.

Comment: This is more of a BIOS problem because it's somehow disallows headless operation.

Comment: How do you know for sure that's the reason? Have you logged data that indicates this is the case? What data do you have?

Answer (score 0):

At power up, system enumerates the monitors by gathering monitor-specific data (called EDID) from each connected monitor (doesnt matter if it is connected via VGA, DVI, HDMI or DP).

So, if you can get an EDID Emulator for DP and plug it in then your system will see it as a monitor. You may need to burn an EDID info into the emulator. That's the way to trick the M/B.

Comment: Well, EDID is a digital protocol so it won't work over VGA anyhow.

Comment: @Octopus Not true. VGA has a pair of I2C pins that are used for EDID.

Comment: Oh okay. I learned something new. [It uses several pins](http://www.extron.com/company/article.aspx?id=uedid), but basically you are correct.